# AngularJs ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I know there is other questions about this problem, but I've ready more than 10 answers and tried every single one and none of them worked for me.

I'm getting this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` when i try to load an external plain javascript file to encode in JWT.

This is the file I'm trying to include with `require()`: https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple I've download with `npm`.

In my code I tried lots of things.

- Include in the `main.js` with grunt concact;
- Load manually inside the `<head>` with the `<script src="path/to/folder"></script>`;
- Install RequireJs with npm for nodeJs;

With all of those attempts, I got the same errors. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I'm using right now:

***index.html***

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jwt.js"></script>
[... rest of head ...]
```

***appCtrl.js*** (will concat later on the build with the rest of the app)

```
.controller('MainCtrl', 
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', 
    function($rootScope, $scope, $state) {
        var jwt = require('jwt');
        var payload = { foo: 'bar' };
        var secret = 'xxx';
        var token = jwt.encode(payload, secret);
        console.log(token);
}])
```

My main objective with this is to handle the user authentication based on a JWT token. The problem right now is to encode/decode the token when the user is login in into the app.

Even with all of these, I still get the error. Do you guys know how to fix this?

Comment: please use the full version of angular js **NOT** .min.js

Comment: @JoeLloyd but why?What is the reason? I've always used this file.

Comment: why are you trying to require that module in Angular? it is for Node. I mean, why you need it there ?

Comment: that's a node module. Why are you trying to load it client side?

Comment: no real errors from .min files

Comment: Here is the answer, you cannot use require() because it does not exist in the client side. Try using requireJS(). Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: I'm trying to get that file because it has functions to encode/decode the JWT I'll use to make the user authentication.

Comment: You cannot do that...

Comment: but isn't jwt encoding a server task? Client just consumes it. As for using dev version of angular...errror and stack trace output is more verbose

Comment: Yeah @charlietfl is right, this is for node.js not for client side angularjs. you won't be able to use it i think

Comment: Ok, but then... How should i proced with it to be able to generate the encoded jwt? Can you guys tell? Because on the docs from `jwt-simple`, it's using a `require(jwt-simple)` so i tought that would be the way.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade: User authentication is handled in backend, where you will generate a token using JWT and send it to your client... your client will store that in session storage and check for authorization for each access...

Comment: Server is nodeJS/mongodb/JWT... you will have rest-end points which will be consumed by angularjs...

Comment: @Thalaivar can you provide an example on how should i proced to create this JWT token on server side? I'm running my webapp with angularjs and php/mysql as backend. And sorry if a newbie question, but I'm new to this and just spent the whole day trying to figure it out.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade on jwt site there are several different php library repos listed. Should be easy to find tutorials also. If you aren't running node server you have the wrong library files

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'll need to use a server encode code to generate my JWT, [like this](https://github.com/emarref/jwt), for php. Then, in my webApp I'll have to have someother function to just decode the token and be able to use the data in my app. For example, show a welcome msg with the logged user name.

Comment: This doesn't even make any sense.  You say in comments that your backend is php, yet you are trying to use a node library here.

Comment: Since I'm new to this, I was following the docs i found, which was based on node. After the comments, i went to another way, using the php library provided by the jwt.io website. But still, I don't know how to use that.. But I'm trying on a better way now

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `require` on the client, you need to use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) (I definitely recommend the latter).

You're getting that error because, in fact, you have never defined `require` anywhere on your client-side code. That JWT repo does not provide that functionality for you.

Also, looking at the docs for the JWT repo you provided, it appears that it expects you to use it in a node.js environment (which provides the commonjs `require` for you).

Comment: After some comments on the question i discovered i need to run it in another way. Since my database is with mysql/PHP I'll have to use it with the PHP library provided by jtw.io. But I'm still trying to figure it out how to install it to encode the token. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side (ie server.js file), for node, use:

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
```

Then, to encode:

```
var secret = "Ieaticecreamforbreakfast";
```

and in your login functionality... once you check the login criteria

```
var token = jwt.encode({id: ID, otherInfo: "can go here"}, secret); 

res.send({token: token});
```

You can then set the response token in as a header for additional http requests in your angular, frontend side.  Therefore, whenever a user makes a request to the backend, you have access to their encoded ID in the JWT

Comment: That was what i tried, but didn't worked. Any idea on how to use it with php backend?